# Passing function to another function: Using a variable within the function as the argument to the functions being passed to it

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

A code example from a JavaScript book. I am learning about passing functions as arguments to functions. The solution explains that when we pass the hawaiianTranslator function to the sayIt function that the string "hello" is the argument for hawaiianTranslator.

Can someone please explain very simply why this is. sayIt doesn't return anything so why/how is the value of phrase being passed to the hawaiianTranslator function.

Thank you in advance

```
function sayIt(translator) {
    var phrase = translator("Hello");
    alert(phrase);
}

function hawaiianTranslator(word) {
if (word === "Hello") return "Aloha"; 
if (word === "Goodbye") return "Aloha";
} 

sayIt(hawaiianTranslator);
```

sayIt(hawaiianTranslator);  alerts "Aloha". How does this happen? I don't understand how the string "hello" is the argument to the function hawaiianTranslator

Comment: Hi, I don´t fully understand the question, could you try to reprhase a little bit to see if I understand the problem?

Comment: sayIt(hawaiianTranslator);  alerts "Aloha". How does this happen? I don't understand how the string "hello" is the argument to the function hawaiianTranslator

I've added this to the question to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing function reference `hawaiianTranslator` into `sayit` function as argument, there you are recieving it in translator variable.  So inside `sayit` function you are calling `translator("Hello")` which will be same as `hawaiianTranslator("Hello")` in effect

```
function sayIt(translator) {
    var phrase = translator("Hello");
    alert(phrase);
}
```

In the above function when you call  `translator("Hello")`, which will invoke `hawaiianTranslator` function with "Hello" as argument.

```
function hawaiianTranslator(word) {
    if (word === "Hello") return "Aloha"; 
    if (word === "Goodbye") return "Aloha";
}
```

This function return the translated word. So in the first function you will get the translated word ("Aloha") in phrase variable.

Comment: Why is it the same? As we alert "hello" the function doesn't return it and the functions value isn't "hello". Could you please explain a little further please. I'm quite new to JavaScript